# Regular Expression for decimal numbers (at max 3 decimal numbers with comma)

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write a regular expression that validates an input text box that should contain only decimal values? The value can have at max 3 decimals (but also none) with comma as the separator.

For example, these values given below are valid:-

```
1,234
1,23
1,2
1
```

These are not valid:

```
1,2345 (too many decimal numbers)
A (a letter is not a number)
  (a space or string empty)
1.234 (used a dot instead of a comma)
```

Comment: Is `,1` valid, for that matter?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
\d+(?:,\d{1,3})?
```

Explained:-

```
\d+        # multiple digits
(?:        # start non-capturing group  
  ,        # a comma
  \d{1,3}  # 1-3 digits
)?         # end non-capturing group, made optional
```

Comment: +1 this is the right answer, but the non-capture group really just adds unnecessary complication IMO

Answer (score 2):

How about `@"\d+,?\d{0,3}"`: 1 or more digits, then an optional comma, then 0 to 3 more digits. This assumes that you allow any number of digits before the comma. In your examples you only have one, in which case you would want to remove the `+`.

If the value `1,` is not valid, you'll have to move the `?` to the end: `@"\d+(,\d{1,3})?"`

Comment: This seems to match `1,` which I believe is a mistake.

Comment: @pguardiario: The OP didn't answer that question. It's quote possible that it's valid.

Comment: That's better, but now you've just repeated Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]{1,3})?
```

Comment: Thank you, could be a solution.

L

Comment: I like this one, for a starter in regexes, this solution is the most straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Note if you only want one character before the decimal, remove the `+`

```
^\d+(,(\d?){3})?$


^   //start
\d+   //one or more decimal digits
(,(\d?){3})?    //a comma, followed by up to 3 decimal digits, optionally
$    //end
```

If you don't want `1,` to be accepted, then the middle section can be `(,\d(\d?){2})?`

Comment: @pguardiario I'm pretty sure it doesn't... I tested it pretty thoroughly. Did you? The ? In the second clause makes each of the 3 decimals optional, such ajar you don't need {1,3}

Comment: (Sorry from the typos, typed on my phone)